# How to bind data to attributes inside an array of objects using the Plates templating engine?

Tags: javascript, templates, flatiron.js

Using [Plates](https://github.com/flatiron/plates), with their [changing sintaxes](https://github.com/flatiron/plates/wiki/Using-data-bind-for-Clean-Plating) (this doesn't work anymore) over the years and poor documentation,

I have this string:

```
<table id="group">
  <tr>
    <td class="name"></td>
    <td>
      <a class="surname"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And this data:

```
{
  group: [{
    name: 'Ludwig',
    surname: 'von Mises',
    url: 'http://mises.org/'
  }, {
    name: 'Friedrich',
    surname: 'Hayek',
    url: 'http://hayek.org/'
  }],
}
```

What should I do to bind `url` to `href`, so I get

```
<table id="group">
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Ludwig</td>
    <td>
      <a class="surname" href="http://mises.org/">Mises</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Friedrich</td>
    <td>
      <a class="surname" href="http://hayek.org/">Hayek</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Faced with a simple problem with others' libraries, I did what any programmer would do in this case: I wrote my own Plates-like (but not a fork of it) templating engine that (maybe) works.

Here it is: https://github.com/fiatjaf/tempreites

(Works with strings, semantic binding, just one file, no dependencies, a simple synchronous function named `render` and it is it.)

(I began writing it after I posted this question here, so it wasn't just for the propaganda.)